# Getting "Error in x * x : non-numeric argument to binary operator" when running function lm(linear Model) in R

Tags: r

```
library("MASS")
data(cats)
lm(formula = Hwt ~ Bwt, data = cats)
```

Error is:

```
 "Error in x * x : non-numeric argument to binary operator" when running function lm(linear Model) in R
```

Comment: I don't get any error with code you have provided.

Comment: Is there any library or module that i am missing while i am running Linear Model, and getting this error.

Comment: please send me result of **sessionInfo()**

Comment: Result of session Info

Comment: R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] MASS_7.3-39   hexbin_1.27.1